# How do I "extract" my commited files?

Tags: linux, git

I have two files `file1.c` and `file1.h` in my working directory `/tmp/working`. Everything I do is on my local file system.

I do a `git init` in `/tmp/working` that creates a `.git` directory in it. Then I `git add file1.*` and `git commit -m "Feb 13th 2017"`.

On Feb 17 I accidentally delete the two files in my working directory. How do I restore my files in my working directory from my local git repository? I don't want to undo the last commit or something like that, just want the copy of my files (version of Feb 13th) back in my working directory.

Comment: Did you use `git rm` to delete? Can you add the output of git status to the question?

Comment: Storing the repository in `/tmp` seems risky, it might get deleted upon rebooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try just checking out those two files from the latest commit:

```
git checkout -- path/to/file1.c
git checkout -- path/to/file1.h
```

The nice thing about Git is that it is hard to really mess things up.  You only deleted those two files locally in the current commit.  But their history is easily accessible using `git checkout`.

---

Actually, any path works:

```
git checkout -- path/to/    # extracts the whole "path/to" directory
git checkout -- .           # extract all the content of the last commit
```

and you can also specify any commit :

```
git checkout other_branch -- path/to/   # extracts content from other_branch
git checkout v1.7.3 -- path/to/         #                  from this tag
git checkout eacf33b -- path/to/        #                  from this commit
```

Comment: And more generally : you can get the content of a file in any other commit by running :    `git checkout [branch_or_commit] -- path/to/file`

Comment: how do i extract the files without specifying each filename separately? restoring to my working directory, from local repository, the whole project the latest version of all files commited? something like arj x archive.arj